# Simple JavaScript Login, Redirects to the user's page (Multiple Users)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, authentication

my school is doing a 5 day html challenge next week and i'm practicing my idea,

To get to the point,

I want to make a login system using an external javascript script that supports multiple users
and when the two login forms are valid from the certain part of the code it will redirect to the users page:
I have the two inputs set up:

```
<center> <h1> Join now! </h1> </center>
</header>
<p> Username </p> <input> </input><p> Password </p> <input>  </input>
<button> Submit </button>
```

Feel free to make any adjustments needed to this code and I'd prefer not to use database's for this project

Thanks for the help guys :)

Oh P.S, 
I only need a three user system

And you may user jquery aswell if necessary

Thanks Again

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk. But there is guideline on stackoverflow that states to ask a question you must have a minimum understanding of the problem. It doesn't seem like you do. Try reading up on the syntax of the html `input` tag and user authentication in general.

Comment: At a minimum, you could define 3 users and passwords in a php file.  ajax to the php page, and allow to proceed to the appropriate php if username/pass matches.  Otherwise you would have all usernames and passwords on the client which wouldn't be even remotely secure.

Comment: I do have a minimum understanding check this out: theslashclan.24.eu and goto admin login

Comment: Cartar, Thanks for the replie mate, could you help me out with the code?

Comment: sure thing, will post in a few...

Comment: Well I'm just saying, the HTML is terribly formatted, and your question isn't telling us how you are going to keep track of the logged in user (by using PHP sessions for example). So, try modifying your question by adding a backend example (like a php script or something).

Comment: He's just a kid, go easy on him.  You can tell by the bad html that he gets the basic concept of it, just doesn't know how to use w3c reference yet apparently.  :)

Comment: Thanks Cartar! Your the first useful person on here so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest login form I can think of.  Obviously not full proof.  You should use encryption and store in database and use sessions and all that jazz.  But this is simple enough.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Join now! </h1>
<form name="login_form" method="POST" action="checkLogin.php">
  <p> Username </p> <input type="text" name="user"> 
  <p>Password </p> <input type="pass" name="pass">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//make an associative array of users and their corresponding passwords.
$user_pass_list = array("Joe" => "1234", "Bob" => "4321", "Sally" => "super");

//assign the 'user' variable passed in the post from html to a new php variable called $user
$user = $_POST['user'];
//assign the 'pass' variable passed in the post from html to a new php variable called $pass
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

//check if the user exists in our array
if(array_key_exists($user, $user_pass_list)){
  //if it does, then check the password
  if($user_pass_list[$user] == $pass){
    echo "Login Success";
  }else{
    echo "Login Failure";
  }
}else{
  echo "User does not exist";
}

?>
```

Comment: Then just download WAMP, fire it up, make a php file and an html file.  Wham, bam, thank you mam.  You got a server with user checking.  :) gl

Comment: Thats the one, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you will only have 3 predefined users that might login. I presume you only want to show the functionality of the application, without building a bullet proof login system. To accomplish this, you could have a form like this:

```
<form>
   <legend>Log In</legend>

   <fieldset>
       <label for="username">Username: </label>
       <input id="username" type="text">

       <label for="password">Password: </label>
       <input id="password" type="password">

       <button id="login" type="button">Log In!</button>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Pure JavaScript validation and redirect:

```
var users = [
    { username: 'user1', password: 'pass1' },
    { username: 'user2', password: 'pass2' },
    { username: 'user3', password: 'pass3' }
];

var button = document.getElementById('login');

button.onclick = function() {
   var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
   var password = document.getElementById('password').value; 

   for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if(username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password) {
         window.location.href = 'http://where/you/want/to/redirect/';
         break;
      }else{
         alert('You are trying to break in!');
      }
   }
}
```

P.S.: This example just shows you how to store the 3 users in an array and how to validate the input on the front-end so that only those users can login.